# NSMutableURLRequest and redirection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

So I am trying to create a request that will automatically follow the redirects in its process.  For some reason this is not working, this is what my delegate method looks like.  Do I need to do anything else for this to function properly?  Thanks!

```
-(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
       redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse*)redirectResponse {
NSLog(@"RedirectResponse:%@", [redirectResponse URL]);
NSLog(@"send request:%@", [request URL]);

NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieDict = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSLog(@"CURRENT COOKIES: %@", [cookieDict cookies]);

/*NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)redirectResponse;
if ([redirectResponse respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSLog([dictionary description]);
}*/

NSURLRequest *newRequest=request; 
return newRequest;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says:

> The delegate may return request unmodified to allow the redirect

So a simple `return request;` should be enough.

Are you sure it is not working? What do you see?

Comment: It's working, but not following the redirects properly.  I feel like it must be a server side error.  Or perhaps I need to backtrack in the process.  I need to trace through a login procedure and collect the cookies along the way.  This should function for that purpose correct?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, had the wrong post data/target.  Thanks for helping me understand how that worked!  I am going to accept your answer.  :)