# Objective C, unable create an XML Post Action

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, post, soap

I am trying to make a POST Action in Objective-C (for an iOS application) to a Biztalk server to send an XML file

I found the following [tutorial](http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/making-a-post-in-objective-c-xcode-to-sharepoint-webservice-requiring-windows-ntlm-authenticaton-for-iphone-or-ipad/) and used it . the code compiles successfully and when I try to post I don t get any error message regarding the posting (through the 
`didFailWithError`   Function). But when I check on Biztalk I noticed that  the data didn't get transmitted ...

the link I am posting to is an https link ( and not http) can this be the problem ?

Am I missing something ?

Thanks!

EDIT : here are the functions that get called sequentially after making the SOAP Request:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

Comment: Can you convert the response to a string and post it?  It might contain a hint as to what is going on.

Comment: ok I found where is the problem (or at lease one of them ) . the link I call redirects several times and I need to use the cookies to create another request with the last redirection . I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670892/nsmutableurlrequest-and-redirection that handles redirection but I need to know how to use the cookies in my second call , can you give me a hint on that ?

Comment: Something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319866/iphone-nsurlconnection-read-cookies

Comment: ok I managed to make calls with cookies history . but now I get another issue , the `didFailWithError` gets called with the following error :`code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects"` !!!! any clue how to handle this problem ?

Comment: The data you are sending the server is probably causing an infinite redirect loop

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Is a nice framework to REST Actions